# Pythonic way to wrap an int into a list in python

Tags: python

I apologize in advance, this must have been asked before, but I just cannot seem to find the right keywords. What I am trying to do is simply to wrap an integer into a list.

```
1 -> [1]
```

Since `append()` doesn't return a new list, the best I can come up with as of now is:

```
myList = []
mylist.append(1)
```

But it just doesn't look pythonic at all... there must be a different way...

What am I missing? Help!

Comment: You've already written it down... lol `[number]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap whatever datatype you want in square brackets and it will become a list,

```
k = 5
klst = [k]
```

Comment: Rotfl grmlgrml... that was just too... easy >_< but that's what I'm talking about, that is pythonic!